# setImage:forState: for UIButton for a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my nib file, I have an outlet connected a UIButton for the UITableViewCell.  Where can I set the image for the different states of the button in code?

By default, there is a method

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier    {

}
```

I tried setting my image for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateSelected, but I don't see my states when I load the TableViewCell.  I load the TBvCell using the UINib method:

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
     if (cell == nil) {
     UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
     [cellNib instaniateWithOwner:self options:nil];
     cell = self.MyCell;
     self.MyCell = nil;
}
return cell;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all this in Interface Builder itself. Unless you have very string reasons to do it in code. Here's how to do it in IB -

Open the right side bar & then click on "State Config", there you see the various states of the button, Default, Highlighted, Selected & Disabled. Now you can set different images for each state, different font type & font colors for each state. Hopr this helps...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could set it there.  It works as expected.  Just out of curiosity, where would I put this code in the UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: if you are setting different states of UIButton through code, then you end up writing verbose code. Instead i would suggest set these states for uibuttons through IB for a particular uitableviewcell & reuse that cell... Its straightforward.